# CompletableFuture runAsync vs Executing each Runnable with an Executor

Tags: java, multithreading, email, asynchronous, java-8

Recently I'm trying to implement an email service that sends email to each user concurrently. My current implementation current looks like this:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
tasks.forEach(executor::execute); // Each task sends an email to an user
executorService.shutdown(); // Reclaim all the resources
```

After some research I've found a new way, using Java 8 `CompletableFuture.runAsync(...)` method. Using this approach I've did:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
tasks.forEach(task -> CompletableFuture.runAsync(task, executor));
executor.shutdown(); // Reclaim all resources
```

Now I'm a little confused what is the best approach for my problem in terms of correctness, scalability and what is the most modern/current approach that solves my problem.

Comment: Or invoke all tasks and wait for completion via `executor.invokeAll(tasks.stream().map(Executors::callable).collect(Collectors.toList()));`. Even easier if the tasks are already `Callable` instead of `Runnable`, as then, you can simply say `executor.invokeAll(tasks)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Executor.execute` will execute your task asynchronously.

`CompletableFuture.runAsync(Runnable, Executor)` also execute your task asynchronously, but, in additionally, return a `CompletableFuture` object, which you can use to chain / plug more dependent tasks.

(Ex, after send email, you want to send a notify to yourself indicate the success:

```
CompletableFuture.runAsync(task, executor).thenRunAsync(this::sendNotify)
```

For your use case, it makes no different.

You can stick with first version of code for simplicity.

Comment: Is there any specific reason you didn't specify executor in ```thenRunSync```?

Answer (score 2):

The latter approach has the advantage that it gives you a `CompletableFuture` object, which can be used to `get` the result of the action, to make sure that the action was completed and to get any exceptions thrown by the action.

Since you do not seem to care for any of that, I guess invoking the executor directly is just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Both solutions are pretty much exactly the same - they both execute the tasks asynchronously on the executor. For this small example there's no difference and the first example is the better because it doesn't create unnecessary `CompletableFuture`s.

However, say that you had this code instead:

```
public class EmailSender {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmailSender.class);

    private final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    public void sendEmails(Collection<String> emails) {
        // make and send emails
        Collection<Runnable> tasks = createEmailTasks(emails);

        // Send them using the executor and then log a message when all emails have been sent, but how?
    }
}
```

Here Java8 and `CompletableFuture` gives you a clear advantage:

```
// Create futures of all tasks
CompletableFuture[] futures = tasks.stream()
    .map(task -> CompletableFuture.runAsync(task, executor))
    .toArray(size -> new CompletableFuture[size]);

// Log a message when all tasks have completed
CompletableFuture.allOf(futures)
    .thenRunAsync(() -> log.info("Email batch sent successfully"), executor);
```

You can also use any of the chaining methods of `CompletableFuture` such as `.thenRun(Runnable)` or `.thenApply(Function<ReturnValue, NewReturnValue>)` (if your tasks have return values) to work on individual tasks.

So, for your current example it doesn't really matter, but using `CompletableFuture` is a lot more flexible and future-proof.

Comment: That's a good approach but it will block the process the email is sent. It cannot be applied for my case but I will take in consideration.

Comment: My bad, I incorrectly remembered `ExecutorService.shutdown()` to wait for all tasks to complete, if you don't want to wait for the tasks nor do anything with the return value of each task/when each task completes there's absolutely no benefit to using `CompletableFuture` for you.

Comment: I've changed my answer to not wait on the tasks but to log a message once all tasks have completed instead.